# How to test POS Terminal Appication in Appium

Tags: javascript, android, sql, transactions, branding

How to test POS Terminal Appication in Appium for validating Sale, Bank and Brand Transaction with Base 24.

I have an Query --How to Validate & which type of Major step mainly taken to validate CTLC Transaction ?

public class CTLSValidationTest {

```
private AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    // Set desired capabilities
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Your_Device_Name");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "path/to/your/app.apk");
    
    // Initialize driver
    URL appiumServerURL = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(appiumServerURL, caps);
}

@Test
public void testCTLSFunctionality() {
    // Your test steps
    // Locate CTLS elements and perform actions
    MobileElement ctlsButton = driver.findElement(MobileBy.id("yourCTLSButtonID"));
    ctlsButton.click();
    
    // Perform CTLS validations
    // ...
}

@AfterTest
public void teardown() {
    // Close the app and quit the driver session
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

}